# merge 4 columns into two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with repeating 4 columns that i would like to merge in 2 columns.

```
Product ID     Year_X     Month_X     Year_Y    Month_Y
    1            2020         1        2014       11
    1            2019         2        2018       10
    2            2022         5        2010       8
    2            2021         1        2019       9
```

The output should be like this:

```
Product ID     Year     Month
    1          2014      11
    1          2018      10
    1          2019      2
    1          2020      1
    2          2010      8
    2          2019      9
    2          2021      1
    2          2022      5
```

Thank you

Comment: this function might help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Answer (score 2):

Create unique index first by `reset_index` then you can use `wide_to_long`:

```
print (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=["Year", "Month"], 
                       i="index", j="Key", sep="_", suffix="\w*")
         .reset_index(drop=True))

   Product ID  Year  Month
0           1  2020      1
1           1  2019      2
2           2  2022      5
3           2  2021      1
4           1  2014     11
5           1  2018     10
6           2  2010      8
7           2  2019      9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two new dataframes by separating the one you have into the columns you want and removing the suffixes. Then use pandas concat to put the two together. The sort_values puts them in the order you want.

```
df1 = df[['Product ID', 'Year_X', 'Month_X']].rename(columns={"Year_X": "Year", "Month_X": "Month"})
df2 = df[['Product ID', 'Year_Y', 'Month_Y']].rename(columns={"Year_Y": "Year", "Month_Y": "Month"})
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by=['Product ID', 'Year']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output is

```
   Product ID  Year  Month
0           1  2014     11
1           1  2018     10
2           1  2019      2
3           1  2020      1
4           2  2010      8
5           2  2019      9
6           2  2021      1
7           2  2022      5
```